# Collection view not loading images

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a collection view set up. I am downloading images from the firebase and then appending to an array which is the data source to the collectionView.

I am calling the function in which i Download images, in the `viewdidLoad()`. and then populate the collection view by `array.count` in `numberOfItemsInSection` method.

Somehow the array is appended after the collection view shows up. Hence no images are loaded in collection view.

What is it that I am doing Wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that downloading runs asynchronously meaning you get your images after reloadData() is performed. If you show some maybe I can give you more helpful answer, but what I can tell you now is that you need to do

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

after you download images.

Comment: Oh god Yes! That is it. It just skipped my mind. Thanks Alot mate.